# Color code difference in 2 strings in jsf

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

I have a requirement where I need to color code characters which are different between two strings. 
For e.g if two strings are `abcd1234df` and `abdc1256dg` then characters in first string at location 3,4,7,8,10 need to be shown in red.

I am using `Jsf 2.0` and `richfaces 4` and I need this solution to be viable in terms of performance as this would have to be done in a loop for around 50 strings.
These Strings are columns in a rich datatable with 50 rows.
Where should i call the javascript method so that one of the column in rich datatable gets color coded

Comment: This should be done purely with JavaScript and CSS. JSF is just a mere HTML generator for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick go at it in javascript.
This will return a `<p>` tag with the letters, and a span for whatever's different marked with the class 'different'.

So if you have css like:

```
.different{
   /*color: red;*/
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Then you run `diffString('abcd1234df','abdc1256dg')` and get this:

ab**cd**12**34**d**f**

actual return:
`<p>ab<span class='different'>c</span><span class='different'>d</span>12<span class='different'>3</span><span class='different'>4</span>d<span class='different'>f</span></p>`

Here's my code:

```
function diffString(originalString, compareString){    
  var returnString = "<p>";    
  for(var i=0, child; child=originalString[i]; i++){    
    if(child != compareString[i]){    
      returnString += "<span class='different'>" + child + "</span>";    
    }    
    else{    
      returnString += child;      
    }    
  }    
  returnString += "</p>";    
  return returnString;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan Files.. I will try this approach and get back

Comment: Hi Alan, These String are shown on screen as columns of a rich datatable. Where should i call the javascript method so that one of the rich column gets color coded